# SQLCMD :connect dynamic parameter

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

In SSMS I have this

```
:SETVAR DBSrvrInst MyDatabase
:connect  ADMIN:$(DBSrvrInst)
```

In the `Messages` tab I get

> Connecting to ADMIN:$(DBSrvrInst)...

The variable isn't being replaced. 
But if I do this and remove the constant

```
:SETVAR DBSrvrInst MyDatabase
:connect  $(DBSrvrInst)
```

In the `Messages` tab I get

> Connecting to MyDatabase...

The variable is replaced correctly.
How do I get this to work

```
:SETVAR DBSrvrInst MyDatabase
:connect  ADMIN:$(DBSrvrInst)
```

I would even be ok with using the port but that doesn't work either

```
:SETVAR DBSrvrInst MyDatabase
:connect  $(DBSrvrInst),1434
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just placing the ADMIN: text in the variable? eg

```
:setvar DBSrvrInst ADMIN:.\sql2014

:connect $(DBSrvrInst)
GO
```

Comment: That would work, but my goal is to connect using the Dedicated Admin Connection to kill some processes using a workload group. Then drop the workload. And then reconnect not using the DAC.

Comment: You did give me an idea to just use two variables. The additional one having the ADMIN: prefix as you suggested. That will probably work, but it seems strange the token replacement for `:connect ADMIN:$(DBSrvrInst)` doesn't work. I'll mark your answer correct after I have a chance to try this. Thanks for your reply.